# Compare a cell value from Workbook 1 with multiple cells in Workbook 2, if matches then +1 in below cell of WB2

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks with different formats, I need to check if the values of One column in workbook 1 matches to a range of cells in workbook 2,
For example if we have 10 students (Workbook1) in a class and they good the respective grades Bad, Good and Very good (workbook2), the principal wants to know the count of how many got Bad , good and very good

I am completely new to VBA, Please anyone help me with this

I started trying the following code, but cannot go further

```
Sub ResultComparison()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A4:A9")
FR As Variant


Set w2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Comparison\ReferanceResult.xlsx").Worksheets("Blad1")
Set w1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Comparison\Results.xlsx").Worksheets("Blad1")


For Each rng1 In w1.Range("rng1", w1.Range("A4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = Application.Match(rng1, w2.Columns("J"), 0)
```

Comment: Use [CountIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)?

Comment: Is vba really the answer, like mentioned above. Countif() would be what is required.